# Prepend/Append (prefix/postfix) Lines in GVim

Tags: c++, vim, comments, append, prepend

I want to be able to **easily** *prepend* `//` to lines using GVim, in order to be able to comments some blocks of code in C++. I tried to do [this](http://geek.chrislott.org/2012/prepend-append-prefix-postfix-lines-vim/):

> To prefix or prepend text to lines using Vim, you can use VISUAL BLOCK
>   mode:
>
> - Use CTRL-V to go into VISUAL BLOCK modeSelect the line(s) you wish to
> - prefix Press I to insert at the beginning of the block Type the text
> - you wish to insert (you will see it only on the current line) Press
> - ESC to exit the mode and prepend the rest of the lines
>
> To postfix or append, you use a similar technique, but with A:
>
> - Use CTRL-V to go into VISUAL BLOCK modeSelect the line(s) you wish to prefix… be sure to select the entire lines (select lines and use $)
> - Press A to append to block
> - Type the text you wish to insert (you will see it only on the current line)
> - Press ESC to exit the mode and prepend the rest of the lines

The only thing I got was just one single `//` at the start of the selected block.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggling comments is a solved problem; don't try to invent your (poor) alternative. The most popular plugins (that I know) are:

- [The NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218)
- [EnhCommentify.vim - comment lines in a program](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=23)
- [tComment - An extensible & universal comment plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173)

Comment: Yeah, I use NERD Commenter, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
CTRL + V
select the lines using arrows (or hjkl)
press I - this puts you into insert mode
Type '// ' (for example)
Hit ESC key to exit insert mode
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Several methods, assuming you want to comment 5 lines and are on the first one:

```
I//<Esc>
j^.
j^.
j^.
j^.

v4j
:'<,'>norm I//<CR> " the range is inserted for you so that's only norm I//<CR>

v4j
:'<,'>s+^+//<cr> " same deal with the range

:,+4norm I//<CR>

:,+4norm s+^+//<cr>

nnoremap <F4> :s+^+//<cr>
```

Or simply use a plugin like [Commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary)

Answer (score 0):

It must be <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, not <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. (Capital V)